# Check if student is nursery,pre-k,kindergarten base on 3 parameters(Date Joined , Birthdate , School's school year)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently having troubles applying the concept of school year in my code , 
one thing that could go wrong If I don't apply
the concept of school year and just use the birthdate and the currentdate to get the child's level
is that it wouldn't detect if that child is still a nursery or already a pre-school.
I already aware that to make this work I need a column that is named 'Date Joined'
 and I already added that to my table. Now my problem is how can I use it.

what I've done so far.

My current sql statement divides into 3 (which I named ClassType)

```
ClassType
**4** - 4 years old below (Nursery)
**5** - between 4 yr old and 6 yr old (Pre-k)
**6** - 6 years old above (kindergarten)
```

sql statement:

```
SELECT 
c.ChildID,
c.ChildName,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, c.Birthdate, CURDATE()) as Age,
cls.ClassID, 
CASE WHEN
 (cls.ClassTypeAgeNo = 2) AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, c.Birthdate, CURDATE()) <= 4 THEN 4 
WHEN
(cls.ClassTypeAgeNo = 2) AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, c.Birthdate, CURDATE()) = 5 THEN 5
WHEN
WHEN (cls.ClassTypeAgeNo = 2) AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, c.Birthdate, CURDATE()) >= 6 THEN 6 
END AS ClassType  

        FROM m_Student c 
        inner join m_Class cls on c.ClassID = cls.ClassID
```

result of the above query
my desired result is still the same but it will have to check if the child
is still on the same level or not base on the School Year

my current code can propery check if the child is on what level but it can't
detect if the child is still on the same level or moved another level.

edit:
the school starts from 2015/04/01 and ends in 2016/03/31.

Comment: Help us help you by providing sample data and expected result.

Comment: I posted some sample data but I don't have enough rep for pictures so I'll write it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough formation on how the joined date influences the level, but I think the solution might be close to this:

```
SELECT 
c.ChildID,
c.ChildName,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, c.Birthdate, CURDATE()) as Age,
cls.ClassID, 
CASE WHEN
 (cls.ClassTypeAgeNo = 2) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, c.Birthdate, c.date_joined) - 
CASE WHEN MONTH(c.date_joined) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <= 4 THEN 4 
WHEN
 (cls.ClassTypeAgeNo = 2) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, c.Birthdate, c.date_joined) - 
CASE WHEN MONTH(c.date_joined) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 5 THEN 5
 WHEN
 (cls.ClassTypeAgeNo = 2) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, c.Birthdate, c.date_joined) - 
CASE WHEN MONTH(c.date_joined) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 6 THEN 6 
END AS ClassType  

        FROM m_Student c 
        inner join m_Class cls on c.ClassID = cls.ClassID
```